# c# lambda query to find matching sub-element

Tags: c#, mongodb, lambda, mongodb-.net-driver

```
var query = Query<MongoData>.EQ(e => e.name, someString);
var entity = collection.FindOneAs<MongoData>(query);
```

And this returns the `MongoData` object in `collection` where the property `name` matches the string (`someString`) I send it.

I'd like to add another query to this to also get the entity that matches `name` and `files.author`

`collection` is an `List`, and `files` is an `List` inside of `collection`.

Currently, I'm doing it the hard way and just looping through `entity.files` until I find a match, but this is painful.

So given a MongoData List that contains one object with a name of `X` and an `files` list that contains an author of `Y`, I'd like to return this one.

Comment: @poke Why do you need to see the rest of the code to answer my question?

Comment: Because it puts me off to see two opening curly braces in a broken method definition like that. It looks like a copy/paste error. And if it doesn’t matter to the question, then what’s the point of posting it as a method (especially with a try block) in the first place? Break it down to the important parts.

Comment: @poke Okay, I edited it out.

Comment: Are you really using ArrayLists? Consider using a generic like List<>. This will avoid boxing/unboxing performance hit, if you hold value types, as these will be cast to object on insertion, and cast back upon read. Read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5bx6xee.aspx)

Comment: @Andreas No, I'm not really using ArrayLists. I actually forgot what I was using and said "ArrayLists" because that's what I learned to use first. They're just Lists. But thanks for telling me why I should use one over the other.

Comment: What do you expect for that new query as the return value? A `MongoData` entity in which `files` list a match exists? Or an object from that files list (whatever type those have)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably do it like this and query multiple properties at once:

```
var query = Query.And(
    Query<MongoData>.EQ(e => e.name, someString),
    Query<MongoData>.ElemMatch(
        e => e.files,
        q => q.EQ(f => f.author, someAuthorName)
    )
);
```

The latter subquery uses the `ElemMatch<TValue>` query function, which expects an expression returning an enumerable of subobjects, and a function that executes another query on each of those subobjects.